# Which verse is the heart of Surah Ya-Sin?

Tags: quran, surat-yasin

As it is relatively considered as a famous issue (that Surah Ya-sin is the heart of Quran), and as a narration, it is quoted that Imam Sadiq (a.s.) said:

> Everything has a heart, and surah Ya-Sin is the heart of the Quran.
>
> صدوق، محمد بن على‏، ثواب الاعمال و عقاب الأعمال

So, I was wondering which verse of Surah Ya-Sin is considered as the heart of this Surah.

Comment: What significance or value does knowing this add to your imaan?
Just curious.

Comment: It is thirst of knowledge brother,,Rumi said  'Two there are who are never satisfied -- the lover of the world and the lover of knowledge.'

Comment: @servant, Lovely sentence! Jazak-Allah-Khaira. On the other hand, if (about my query) we want to say "What significance or value does knowing this add to your imaan?", subsequently we can remark it about manyyyy of this site questions and other questions... / Good luck fair mate.

Answer (score 3):

Although the statement *Everything has a heart, and surah Ya-Sin is the heart of the Quran* is properly documented, what you are asking is not. Let me try to give an answer with argument.

Coming to my argument, since Yasin is already called a heart, it doesn't have to have its own heart. But there is something called the **deepest part of the heart**, and by Allah, I believe the deepest part of this heart is the last two verses taken together:

> [36.82](http://quranx.com/36.82-83) Verily, His Command, when He intends a thing, is only that He says to it, "Be!" and it is!
>
> [36.83](http://quranx.com/36.83) So Glorified is He and Exalted above all that they associate with Him, and in Whose Hands is the dominion of all things, and to Him you shall be returned.

These two verses are indeed very profound in meaning, and this is the primary message of the whole Quran.

*I expect my argument to be agreed upon.* Jazak Allah Khair.

Comment: @servant .. Salam brother, this is completely my opinion and argument as the heart of surah yasin is not documented anywhere. please read it once again.

Comment: @servant the first part states there is no such documented thing.  Then it goes on to say 'I believe... ' intending to imply this is a personal matter.  Perhaps an edit would make it clearer

Comment: ok I apologize for not going through it thoroughly.

Answer (score 1):

Suar "Yasin" is heart of Quran, as Prophet(pbuh) said,"Everything has a heart, and surah Ya-Sin is the heart of the Quran". And Heart of Surah "Yasin" is This verse,
"﴾قَوۡلًا مِّنۡ رَّبٍّ رَّحِيۡمٍ‏ ﴿۵۸سَلٰمٌ

Comment: Good short answer, albeit it would be nicer if you add ref. for your appropriate answer. Anyway, well done. God bless you.